# Dialogflow access agent history using Rest api

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

hello guys i am developing a chatbot using Dialogflow and i want to see the agent history on my own page can someone help how to access the agent history using api?

Comment: Can you use chatbase for that? https://chatbase.com/documentation/docs-overview

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to access agent history via API.